# RMSE of two data sets of unequal lengths in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I want to calculate the RMSE of two unequal data sets.

Dataset 1 has the dimensions 1067x1 and dataset 2 has the dimensions 2227x1.

How do I calculate the RMSE?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer not knowing the data.
One option is interpolate the length of one vector to the other. That gets more accurate if you have e.g. timestamps for the two datasets.

```
v1 = rand(1067,1);
v2 = rand(2227,1);

v1_int = interp1(1:size(v2,1)/size(v1,1):size(v2,1), v1, 1:size(v2,1), 'linear', 'extrap')';
sqrt(mean((v1_int-v2).^2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [interpolate](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) the smaller vector before proceeding with the `RMSE` calculation, as follows:

```
d1 = randn(1067,1);
d1_len = numel(d1);
d2 = randn(2227,1);
d2_len = numel(d2);

d1 = interp1(1:(d2_len / d1_len):d2_len,d1,1:d2_len,'linear','extrap');

plot(d2,'b');
hold on;
plot(d1,'r')
hold off;
```

Alternatively, [downsample](https://mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/downsample.html) and [upsample](https://mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/upsample.html) functions can be used instead but they require more attention on the final output data and length. Once this is done, you can obtain the `RMSE` using this code:

```
RMSE = sqrt(mean(((d2 - d1) .^ 2)));
```

The `RMSE` is actually defined as the squared root of the mean of the squares of the errors, where the errors are given by the difference between observed values `y` and predicted values `ycap`... so choose carefully which one of your vectors represents the former and which one the latter. For more information, read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error).